# how to retrieve object from java hashSet

Tags: java, performance, collections, hashset

I am looking for a way to retrieve object from hashSet in Java. I did iteration over its elements like this:

```
for (Customer remainingNode : availableNodes) {
remainingNode.setMarginalGain(calculateMarginalGain(
                    remainingNode, seedSet, network, availableNodes,
                    churnNet));
}
```

Unfortunately due to concurrent modification Exception I have to change that to something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<numberofRemainingNodes;i++){
Customer remainingNode=availableNodes.get(i);
remainingNode.setMarginalGain(calculateMarginalGain(
                        remainingNode, seedSet, network, availableNodes,
                        churnNet));
numberofRemainingNodes=availableNodes.size();
}
```

But I can not do that because there is not any get(index) method for Java hashSet. Would you please help me to handle this situation?

P.S: I used HashSet because of I want to handle the union and intersection situation and I did not want to add duplicate element to that. Please consider that this part of my program should be run millions of times so a little extra latency could be expensive for whole program.

FYI:

```
private int calculateMarginalGain(Customer remainingNode,
            HashSet<Customer> seedSet,
            DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> net,
            Set<Customer> availableNodes, HashSet<Customer> churnNetwork) {
        // Marginal gain for short-term campaign
        HashSet<Customer> tmp = new HashSet<Customer>(); // seedset U
                                                            // {remainingNode}
        tmp.add(remainingNode);
        Set<Customer> tmpAvailableNodes = availableNodes;
        HashSet<Customer> NeighborOfChurn = getNeighbors(churnNetwork, net);
        // sigma function for calculating the expected number of influenced
        // customers- seedSettmp=seedset U {u}
        tmpAvailableNodes.removeAll(NeighborOfChurn);
        Set<Customer> influencedNet = getNeighbors(tmp, net);
        tmpAvailableNodes.retainAll(influencedNet);
        return tmpAvailableNodes.size();
    }

private HashSet<Customer> getNeighbors(HashSet<Customer> churnNetwork,
        DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> net) {
    HashSet<Customer> churnNeighbors = churnNetwork;
    Collection<Customer> neighbors = new HashSet<Customer>();
    for (Customer node : churnNetwork) {
        neighbors = net.getNeighbors(node);
        for (Customer neighbor : neighbors) {
            churnNeighbors.add(neighbor);
        }
    }
    return churnNeighbors;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that.  Change your code to not modify the set concurrently.  In particular, note that collections are not thread-safe.

Comment: I cant, I did that to decrease the number of iteration that main loop should run. Doing that would decrease the program performance.

Comment: Use another structore like `Map<Customer, Boolean> availableNodes = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()`.

Comment: what does the calculateMarginalGain method do?  Sounds like it modifies availableNodes.

Comment: what other code is accessing availableNodes?

Comment: Show us the code of `setMarginalGain`.

Comment: calculateMarginalGain method is added.

Comment: @AdamArold It is just a simple setter method.

Comment: As an aside, iterating a HashSet is actually *slower* than a List. I don't see you do anything where you actually benefit from using a HashSet.

Comment: I did that in other parts of my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you change the structure of your HashSet during the iteration It is within the calculateMarginalGain() method, in this line:

```
tmpAvailableNodes.removeAll(NeighborOfChurn);
```

Think twice whether this is really right! If yes, then you can work easily around the problem by making you a copy of the set for the iteration first. E.g.:

```
Set<Customer> copy = new HashSet<Customer>;
copy.addAll(availableNodes);
for (Customer : copy) {
  ....
}
```

Actually tmpAvailableNodes and availableNodes are the identical set. Maybe you can improve here in general.

Comment: It is really strange!!! when I use Set<Customer> copy=availableNodes I still get concurrent modification exception, but when I use that in your way, it works! Would you please explain why?!

Comment: The variables copy and availableNodes, both are a reference to an object. In your case it is the identical object because you assinged the reference. There is nothing strange about it, its just a basic java concept....

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<Customer> custIter = availableNodes.iterator();
while(custIter.hasNext()) {
    Customer customer = custIter.next();
    // do your work here
}
```

Using this you won't get `ConcurrentModificationException`. It is not clear why you get it though. If you are tampering with the `HashSet` from multiple `Thread`s consider using a concurrent data structure instead.

If you modify `availableNodes` in `setMarginalGain` you will still get the exception though.

Comment: This won't save from `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: He is not trying to add to the `Set` he is just calling a method on each element.

Comment: I still got cuncurrentModificatinoException.

Comment: I know but if he is `remove`ing something he can pass the `Iterator` to `setMarginalGain` so he can call `remove` on the `Iterator`.

Comment: internally foreach use an iterator, it is make the the same but in other way.